# Relative text centering. Vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontally and vertically center a pre tag without the use of tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886094/horizontally-and-vertically-center-a-pre-tag-without-the-use-of-tables)

How do I horizontally and vertically center text without specifying the width?

Now I have:

```
<div class="center">
<p id="logo"><span>Coming soon!</span></p>
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
span {
    color:#ff0000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
.center {
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Because the text would be different widths, I need another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Give your center class the following CSS:

```
text-align:center;
line-height: 100px;
```

Note that this will only work for a single line of text. See an example at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXVcR/)**.