# Vertically center unknown length of text inside a div

Tags: css, html, positioning

I want to center an unknown length of text (ok it's limited to a certain size, but I don't know if it needs one line or two lines) inside a div. Therfore I cannot use `line-height`. I tried to use `display: table-cell`, but than the layout is destroyed. I cannot use some tricks with `top` because I need this for positioning.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hSCtq/).

Mockup:

[image: Mockup]

**Original code:**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="background">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="TileText">MyText - Another long, long, long text</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.background{
    background-color:#000;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;   
}

.TileText{
    position: relative;
    top: -135px;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #black;
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 10px;  
}
```

**Current state:**

*HTML:*

```
<img src="images/castle.png" width="300" height="333" title="Castle" alt="Castle" />
<div class="TileTextWrapper">
    <div class="TileText">Text</div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.TileTextWrapper{
    position: relative;
    top: -135px;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #57abe9;
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: table;
}

.TileText{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Update:**

Now the text is vertically aligned. But I'm afraid `display: table` would only work with modern browser.

Comment: Browser compatibility of `display` property: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display#compatibilitysection

Comment: This method of centering with display: table will definitely work in IE8 and up.

Comment: Check out http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/. Works well, and if you want it to work with older browsers you just need to add an element into the code instead of using `:before`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle:

It seems to work

see: http://jsfiddle.net/hSCtq/11/ for reference.

I would put `.TileText` inside of `.background`. Creating an empty div for the sake of a background image is not semantically correct, and not necessary in most situations. One situation for a separate background div would be if you need to set the opacity of a background image separately from the content.

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="TileText">MyText - Another long, long, long text</div>
</div>


.background {
    background-color:#000;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;   
    display: table
}

.TileText{
    max-width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 10px;  
}
```

---

Other questions with the same answer.

[Horizontally and vertically center a pre tag without the use of tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886094/horizontally-and-vertically-center-a-pre-tag-without-the-use-of-tables/8887022#8887022)

[The old center a image in a div issue ( image size variable - div size fixed )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874254/the-old-center-a-image-in-a-div-issue-image-size-variable-div-size-fixed/8874346#8874346)

Also, the first result from googling "center vertical text css" will give you the same code structure I posted in my JSfiddle

Comment: take it easy on the negative voting. JS-Fiddle didn't update my code like I thought it had. Just trying to help but the negative voting doesn't encourage me to do so. Thanks. Considering *that there is no* code posted in the original answer for future reference, updating the jsfiddle is a totally reasonable response to the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I will also update my question with code. But I see you removed the positioning of my div, but I want to keep it. In addition, `.background` has an error with `display: table`.

Comment: Either you miss a `;` or you mean `display: table-cell;`. But I have to test your code first.

Comment: Again, downvoting the answer 60 seconds after it's been posted is not constructive.

Comment: jsfiddle was being buggy in updating the code... the current link in the answer centers the text successfully... or you can look at the fiddles from the duplicate questions. http://jsfiddle.net/hSCtq/11/

Comment: As I said I haven't voted now. In reality, I'm not using the div. Instead there is an image, but I don't wanted to include an image, because a div should also do the job. Still must look through the code ...

Comment: The comment was addressed to whomever downvoted... not to you if you didn't downvote. It might help if you include a mockup of the layout you're trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: I added an mockup to my question. I also included my current code (but only a snippet to reduce complexity).

Comment: I personally think that just posting a link to a jsfiddle without any supporting rationale in the body of the question constitutes a generally poor answer, no matter how much awesomeness is contained within the fiddle itself. That was why I downvoted it initially, but have since upvoted instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<p>` tag inside your TileText div :

**HTML**

```
<div class="background"> &nbsp; </div>
<div class="TileText"><p>MyText - Another long, long, long text</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background{
    background-color:#000;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;   
}

.TileText{
    position: relative;
    top: -135px;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #black;
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 10px; 
}

.TileText p { 
    position:absolute;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle

  }
```

**Example here: http://jsbin.com/ubixux/2/edit**

Answer (score 0):

You must add `display:table-cell;` and also add `vertical-align:middle;`

Comment: Where should I add this? If I add this to `.TileText` than the text is centered, but the div is displayed at the bottom.

Comment: So what you want is for the text to be centered in the div in addition to the div being centered vertically in relation to the page?

Comment: The div should not be centered vertically, but I want to define the position for the div (as in my code).

Answer (score -1):

To achieve vertical alignment, you have to use table. You can write your code as this:

```
 <div style="width:600px; height:600px; border:#000000 1px solid;">

    <table style="width:100%; height:100%; vertical-align:middle">
        <tr>
            <td>
    MyText - Another long, long, long text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```